How can I write down the flux for three initial state?
I'm studying about the cross section of collision process.
First, consider a process $a+b \rightarrow f_1 +f_2 + ...+f_n $.
In this case, a beam flux $\Phi_b$ is given by
$\Phi_b = |\vec{\beta_a} -\vec{\beta_b}| $(in NU units),where $\beta$ is a velocity of the particle.
Then, the cross section $\sigma$ is
$\sigma = \frac{1}{2E_a2E_b |\beta_a-\beta_b|} \int \Pi_{f=1}^{n} \frac{d^3\vec{p_f}}{(2\pi)^32E_f} |M_{fi}|^2 \times (2\pi)^4 \delta^{(4)}(\sum_{f}p_{f} - (p_a+p_b)) $.
In the above problem, to find the flux, I first stopped a and found that in the frame where b is moving, the flux is given as $\beta_b$, and in the frame where b is stationary, the flux is given as $\beta_a$. From this, I went through the process of inferring that the general flux is given as the relative velocity $|\beta_b - \beta_a|$.
Now, I want to consider three initial particle case $a+b+c \rightarrow f_1 + f_2 + ... + f_n$.
How should I approach this problem?
